# Java Error substring

Tags: java, string, substring

I have code like this :

```
List<RFeeAtmbVO> list = RFeeAtmbBO.getInstance().listRFeeAtmb(mapParam, null);
if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
  for (RFeeAtmbVO vo : list) {
    vo.setIdFeeType(edit_biaya_jenisBiayaId.getValue());
    String name = edit_biaya_name.getValue().trim();
    if (vo.getName().indexOf("(Gagal Berbayar)") > -1) {
      name = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(" (Gagal Berbayar)")) + " (Gagal Berbayar)";
      System.out.println("Hasilnya 1: "+name);
    } else {
      if (name.indexOf("(Gagal Berbayar)") > -1 ) {
        name = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(" (Gagal Berbayar)"));
        System.out.println("Hasilnya2 : "+name);
      }
    }
    vo.setName(name);
    vo.setSdate(edit_biaya_sdate.getValue());
    vo.setEdate(edit_biaya_edate.getValue());
    vo.setKodeFee(edit_biaya_kodeFee.getValue());
    vo.setMappingCode(edit_biaya_mappingCode.getValue());
    RFeeAtmbBO.getInstance().updateRFeeAtmb(vo);
  }
}
```

When I add in textbox with "(Gagal Berbayar)" without quote is no problem and saved in database, but add some text without "(Gagal Berbayar)", I get the error like this :

```
[err] java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
[err]   at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1904)
[err]   at controller.fee.fee.EditBiayaController.onClick$edit_biaya_btnSave(EditBiayaController.java:413)
```

And Line 413 is

```
name = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(" (Gagal Berbayar)")) + " (Gagal Berbayar)";
```

What the problem? Can help me please? sorry for late update code :)

Comment: I think you just simply need to substracl 1 at indexof. Use this: substring(0, name.indexOf(" (Gagal Berbayar)")-1)

Comment: Please simplify your code example and show some example inputs that trigger the problem. There is a lot of code we don't need to see there - just focus on the substring stuff and demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Answer (score 1):

In the `if` clause you're first checking whether `vo.getName()` contains your string `(Gagal Berbayar)` but then inside the block that executes if the `if` evaluates to `true`, you work with a different expression `name` instead of `vo.getName()`. There is no guarantee that `name` contains your string so this may fail.

You can fix that like this.

```
if (vo.getName().indexOf("(Gagal Berbayar)") > 0) {
  name = vo.getName().substring(0, vo.getName().indexOf(" (Gagal Berbayar)")) 
      + " (Gagal Berbayar)";
  System.out.println("Hasilnya 1: "+name);
}
```

However what if someone just enters `(Gagal Berbayar)` without a space in front of it? Then your `if` statement evaluates to `true` but the `indexOf` inside the block returns -1 because it can't find `(Gagal Berbayar)` (with a space in front of it).

So you should change that too:

```
    String GAGAL = " (Gagal Berbayar)";

    if (vo.getName().indexOf(GAGAL) > 0) {
      name = vo.getName().substring(0, vo.getName().indexOf(GAGAL)) + GAGAL;
      System.out.println("Hasilnya 1: "+name);
    } else {
      if (name.indexOf(GAGAL) > 0 ) {
        name = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(GAGAL));
        System.out.println("Hasilnya2 : "+name);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code `name.indexOf(" (Gagal Berbayar)")`
returns you -1.

And [negative indices are not allowed in substring method.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#subSequence(int,%20int))
So this is a root cause.

Comment: I also think the same. But what if there is a space in `name`. For example - `"asdf sf".indexOf("sf")` and `"asdf sf".indexOf(" sf")`. I think @user3562918 should clarify what `name` actually contains.